# "IS" not recognized in SQL Server in column expression?

Tags: sql, sql-server, null

First line of my view (query?), basically trying to do this:

```
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT dbo.TableName.Field1
, dbo.TableName.Field2
, IIF(dbo.TableName.Field3 IS NOT NULL, 1, 0) AS SomeAlias
```

But for some reason it doesn't like the "IS" keyword and gives me the error that it isn't recognized, even though if I put a random field with "IS NOT NULL" in the WHERE clause, that works fine. I do this sort of thing in MS Access all the time, is it not allowed to create columns using expressions?

Comment: Case statement or ISNULL may accomplish what you need to give you something to dig into.

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using? IIF was introduced in SQL Server 2012.

Comment: "SQL Server Management Studio", I am not sure how to check the version itself

Comment: Just FORGET you ever learned about "TOP (100) PERCENT" - it does nothing useful! And a view, like a table, has no inherent order. Need order in resultset? Then the query that generates it must have an ORDER BY clause.

Comment: When I go to make a new View it auto-inserts the top 100 percent thing even if I try to remove it, so I figured it was mandatory

Comment: @user525966 - you are using the GUI to create a view, and that GUI is notoriously bad.  It doesn't allow a lot of things that are available in T-SQL.  Open a new query window - create your select statement - then wrap that in a CREATE VIEW.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that condition in IIF shouldn't be a problem.

as you can check here  *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=a5122eccb2ee176476d10a4ab19a2fd2)*
it works ok.

but alternatively you can use `case` :

```
...
, case when dbo.TableName.Field3 IS NOT NULL then 1 else 0 end AS SomeAlias
```

Answer (score 0):

You can case instead.

```
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT dbo.TableName.Field1
, dbo.TableName.Field2
, (case when dbo.TableName.Field3 IS NOT NULL then 1 else  0 end)  AS SomeAlias
from dbo.TableName
```